# Resistance of a plank when bullet is fired

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

A bullet fires with a velocity of $1600 ms^{-1}$ passes through three planks in succession .If it losses a velocity of $400ms^{-1}$ in passing through each plank,find the ratio of their thickness to which the resistance is supposed to be proportional.

**DOUBT**-My book has given the solution by considering the principle of Work Power and Energy $$\frac{1}{2}m\times(1200)^2-\frac{1}{2}m\times (1600)^2=-xR.x$$

I know what *Work Power and Energy* theorem implies but we know that work done by resistance force will be $$=-R.x$$
then why they considering it $-xR.x$

( $m$ - mass of bullet ; $x$ - lenght of plank ; $R$ - resistance of plank)

Please help

Thank you

Comment: Check whether $R$ is the resistive force per meter ($N/m$). If it were so, then for $x$ meters, the force would be $-Rx$, then work would become $(-Rx)\cdot x$

Comment: This is not mentioned in book ,may be they are making mistake here

Comment: I think it should be in $N/m$, cause it is mentioned that "resistance is proportional to the thickness"...

Comment: thank you @Ak19,yes it is $N/m$